# Facebook Sharer from Embed Flash Application

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, facebook

I have a small problem with a the Facebook sharer.php!

I'm developing a small flash application (kind of slideshow) that will be embed into different website.

In the application there is a button that send a request to Facebook to share a link.

So based on the Sharer.php doc, I send a request like this :

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.monsite.com&t=Greetings%20from%20Malta%20and%20Morocco.%20Visit%20this%20webpage.
```

The facebook page pops out, I see the correct title for 2 seconds and then facebook replace it with the title of the current page.

Is there a way of preventing Facebook of rewriting the title that I chose?

I know that I can use this in the head of my HTML document :

```
    <meta name="title" 
      content="Smith hails 'unique' Wable legacy">
<meta name="description" 
      content="John Smith claims beautiful football ..." />
<link rel="image_src" 
      href="http://www.onjd.com/design05/images/PH2/WableAFC205.jpg" />
```

But the problem is that I can't control the webpage where this app will be embed.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Cheers,

Jk_

Answer (score 0):

If you could product your application with JS Wrapper, then you could call ExternalInterface to change DOM models attributes and change title and meta tags.

Or what about `facebook -> your html page -> iframe tag with your swf`?